# ASMX web service not generating async functions

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

I made a c# web service (new website > asp.net web service) with 1 function that was auto generated :

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello User";
    }
}
```

I also made a winform app and added a reference to that service and tried to call HelloWorldAsynch but all I had was HelloWorld

```
new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient().HelloWorldAsynch?
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `HelloAsync`? I guess you tried that too.

Comment: Or `HelloWorldAsync` based on your question rather than the posted code.

Comment: I suggest you  use web application projects instead, and WCF instead of ASMX.

Comment: The file name is Service1.asmx

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is that I added the web service as a service reference and not as a web reference

Fix : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx